# Produce a subtotal using filtered data in a table in Excel

Tags: excel

What I want to do is produce a subtotal using filtered data in a table, that doesn't change when I remove the filter from the table.

When I try using the 'subtotal' function, it produces the data I need, but as soon as I remove the filter from the table, the sum changes with the new cells added.

In short I want a subtotal from all 'x' entries in the table, even when the table itself is not showing the filtered data.

Is this possible?

Comment: after you have the correct subtotal, copy and paste it as values?

Comment: Temporarily set calculation to manual ?

Answer (score 0):

please check this:

```
=SUBTOTAL(9;Table1[#All])
```

in the above example, have created a table which name is Table1 and I have tried the subtotal with the sum, I have checked with filters and without and works.